# PHP apply "double" even odd classes

Tags: php

let´s say I´m creating divs in a loop:

```
 $i = 0;
 while ($i < 20) {
    echo '<div class="…">x</div>';
 $i++;
  }
```

How can I apply classes in this rythm

```
<div class="even">x</div>
<div class="odd">x</div>
<div class="odd">x</div>
<div class="even">x</div>
<div class="even">x</div>
<div class="odd">x</div>
<div class="odd">x</div>
…
```

(Double Zebra)

I´m always ending in somethin like:

```
$i%2 ? 'even':'odd';
```

which would give me

```
even
odd
even
odd
```

(Zebra striped)

thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use CSS3 n-th selector?

Comment: Yes, same question as Marco's,   div:nth-chile(even) doesn't work?

Comment: @Jaaaaaaay wouldn't that give you the simple zebra instead of a double-zebra? But still it's possible with via a `element:nth-child(4n-1), element:nth-child(4n) { ...` rule.

Comment: this is a simplified example in real it´s a bit more complex as I have to split strings from filenames and apply phrases in this rythm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do :

```
 $i = 0;
 while ($i < 20) {
     $class = ($i%4 < 2) ? 'odd' : 'even';
     echo '<div class="'.$class.'">x</div>';
     $i++;
 }
```

Comment: Close, this only goes `even, odd, odd, even, odd, odd...` but OP wants `even, odd, odd, even, even, odd, odd` so both even and odd double.

Comment: Right this end ins a Zebra Stripe.

Comment: Raphaël Vigée You did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Many possible solutions, one example:

```
$i%4 < 2 ? 'even':'odd'
```

edit: or using CSS3's nth-child selector:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>...</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            table.doublezebra tr {
                background: #ccc;
            }
            table.doublezebra tr:nth-child(4n-1), table tr:nth-child(4n)  {
                background: #eef;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="doublezebra">
            <tr><td>A</td></tr>
            <tr><td>B</td></tr>
            <tr><td>C</td></tr>
            <tr><td>D</td></tr>
            <tr><td>E</td></tr>
            <tr><td>F</td></tr>
            <tr><td>G</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If more than 2 values (even/odd), I prefer to use an array like:

```
$classes = array('even', 'odd', 'odd', 'even');

for($i=0; $i<20; $i++){
    $clsIdx = $i % count($classes);
    echo "{$classes[$clsIdx]}<br>";
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/vlCHdv

This allows for any values to repeat in any order.